# Trigger Office JS event when clicking on an Excel hyperlink

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Is it possible to call an Office Addin's function when clicking on an Excel cell hyperlink? I checked the documentation, but couldn't find a way.

Anyone had a smart insight making hyperlink events work?

Thanks!

---

**Scenario 1**

I'd like to create a nice user experience where my App loads a table having a column with hyperlink cells in each rows with text `Details`. Whe the user clicks on this hyperlink, the task pane show additional details for the clicked row - by calling a JS function.

**Scenario 2**

I'd like to create a navigation experience inside the worksheet, not in the App Pane. This could be accomplished with native hyperlinks, but in my case, I would need to pull additional data from a database and change the view of the App Pane - by calling a JS function.

**Scenario 3**

I'd like to display a popup when clicking on a hyperlink button inside a worksheet. I would just set a nice formatting to a hyperlink so it would look like a button and the call `displayDialogAsync`.

**Scenario 4**

A given table is showing only the first 20 records from a query. By clicking in `Next` or `Previous` hyperlinks in the spreadsheet, the data updates with the paginated query.

Comment: Could you please share your scenario? we would like to see if there is some workaround solution. office js current do not provide hyperlink click event, we would like to learn more about your scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I gave four examples!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the scenarios. do you want to have before hyper link click event or after hyper link click, from some the scenario, sounds like before hyper link click event. there is a possbility to build after hyper link clicked event, i would like to learn if the link is click, it will navigate to a browser. which is out side of Excel. is this your expected behavior? or how you could control this side effect?

Comment: After thinking a lot, to have consistency, I would suggest that the Excel Js event to be exactly like VBA's `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event. It is an "after clicked" event and currently it is not possible to prevent hyperlink navigation (or, as you said, side effects).
However there is a dirty trick: create a new worksheet, set the hyperlink target to any cell in this new worksheet and then hide the worksheet.
Now, when clicking on a hyperlink in the original worksheet, nothing happens and I just get the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` logic.

Comment: Hello Raymond! Are there any news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my question because I found a satisfactory workaround.

[When creating an hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangehyperlink?view=excel-js-preview), set the `address` property to `#`. This will create a hyperlink that has no action when clicked.

Then, register the event `onSingleClicked` to know in which cell the user clicked on the worksheet. I suggest you to get the sample in [ScriptLab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/#:%7E:text=Script%20Lab%2C%20a%20Microsoft%20Garage,for%20Mac%2C%20and%20Office%20Online.) to know how to register and use the event.

With that, you'll have a nice experience of clicking on hyperlilnks and assigning actions to them. The only drawback is if the user clicks the cell's *background* where the hyperlink is, the event will also fire, but that's good, just make a narrow space between hyperlink's content its cell's background.

Comment: This is how this is handled w/ VBA as well, but can I suggest adding some code to your answer?

Comment: Hi, sure, it would be great.

Comment: Lol, I meant you had some sample code! I'm considering writing up my own answer but this was pretty spot on just no code